# web2py 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) accessing function defined in another apps module

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, web2py, pythonanywhere

I have 2 applications working which share database in mysql.
1)Billing App
2) Accounting App

so after i make entry in app 1 , its results needs to post in app2 database in accountancy voucher form.
so what i did was

i created a module in app2 and tried to import  it in app1 using follwing,

from applications.Accounting.modules.default1 import bill_ledger_processing

where bill_ledger_processing is only function i defined with @auth.requires_login()  code of that function is as follows:
`##################################.app2/modules/default1.py ########################################

```
import requests


from gluon import current
#from gluon.tools import Auth
auth=current.auth
cache=current.cache
import os
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

print("ok")
request = current.request


def exists(path):
    r = requests.head(path)
    return r.status_code == requests.codes.ok

from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

@auth.requires_login()
def bill_ledger_processing(sessionpid,sessionjt,sessionldate,
                           sessionDescription.....................):
#def bill_ledger_processing():#https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/fnN3qa6brzA
   
   

    print(auth.user)
    import datetime
    from gluon import SQLFORM
    #db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
    db = current.dba

    dba = current.db
    session=current.session
     .   .
     ....  
     ....    
     ...   
     . . . . .   
     return locals()
```

#

`

and now coming to issue....

when i call app2 module function by importing in app1...

`

```
############################# app1/controller/default.py ##################
@auth.requires_login()
def printssss():      
    rows=request.vars.row     
    mode=request.vars.mode
    ...
    .....    


  bill_ledger_processing(sessionpid,sessionjt,sessionldate,sessionDescription.....................)     return dict(rows=rows,mode=mode)
#############################################################################
```

`

```
`
##################################### app1/views/print.html ###########################################
<script>

    jQuery('#printbutton').click(function(){

            ajax('{{=URL('default', 'printssss')}}',['rec','mode'],function(html) {
                     jQuery('#callback-target').html(html);

                       printWindow = window.open("http://print.com", "_blank");
                       printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
                       printWindow.document.write('<style type="text/css"> @media print{ th, td {font-size: 14px;  } body {display:inline;font-family:"Consolas"; font-size: 14px;}  @page{ size: 6in 6in; margin:auto; margin-left: 10mm; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0mm; margin-bottom: 0px;padding-top:0px;  }}</style>');
                       printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
                       printWindow.document.write('<p>');
                       printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('callback-target').innerHTML);
                       printWindow.document.write('</p>');
                       printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                       printWindow.print();
                       printWindow.close();
                       $("#callback-target").html("");
               });

        });
});

</script>


#################################################################################`
```

while clicking print button it will print the invoice from app1's def printssss(): and then it will execute bill_ledger_processing(.....)

NOW SOMETIMES   WHILE EXECUTING bill_ledger_processing it will throw error as 401 unauthorized ? i.e

```
jquery.js:4 

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/printssss 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/printssss".
```

this error seems so random that every time  when i kill server and restart it works for some time or days without intruption and suddenly  error appears.
ALSO  clearing cache in web2py admin or browser did not help, also some times the restart will fix the issue or sometimes it doent
the project has hosted in pythonanywhere where i faced similar problem as that of my laptop.

i can not debug this since clicking on error ticket will recall  printssss() with empty form values...

Not able to move ahead with bug. please help me.
 
 
Thanks and Regards

Comment: why would this be a post to 127.0.0.1? Is this hosted on PythonAnywhere on your local machine?

Comment: The `bill_ledger_processing` function is decorated with `@auth.requires_login`, which requires the user be logged into *app2* at the time of the call. Is it possible you are simply not logged into *app2* (or your login has expired) at the times that it fails?

Comment: @conard  its hosted in both local i.e 127.0.0.1 as well as in pythonanywhere on 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Anthony yes u might be right!!

what i have done is assigned same auth_use name and id for both apps and i am sharing session of app1 to app2 to authenticate using current.session 

btw how to check  for login expired  in web2py . which setting for session expiry would be idel to use in my case.

Comment: @Anthony  can you take look at this code

` from gluon import current
#from gluon.tools import Auth
auth=current.auth`

i am trying to call bill_ledger_processing from app1 fuction using app1 authentication. without authenticating app2.

so i did was signup both apps in order to maintain same user credentials for both apps... i did without proper uderstanding. can you thouw some light on it.

Comment: Rather than decorating `bill_ledger_processing`, try applying the auth decorator only to the controller actions in each app that call that function. Then you don't have to worry about sharing authentication.

Comment: thank you @Anthony i think i got it. i had decorated both functions. now i will decorate only the app1 calling function.